# Trying to use Caffe2 to add two blobs together that contain matrices

Tags: caffe2

I'm trying to add the values of two blobs together.  These blobs contain a matrix that is `2,2`.

```
workspace.FeedBlob("X", np.random.randn(2, 2).astype(np.float32))
workspace.FeedBlob("Y", np.random.randn(2, 2).astype(np.float32))
net = core.Net('net')
sum_stuff = net.Add([X, Y])
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did not work? The following example will create two 2x2 matrices and add them together:

```
from caffe2.python import workspace, model_helper, core
import numpy as np

# create 2x2 matrices with random integer from 0 to 9
# and feed them to the workspace
workspace.FeedBlob("X", np.random.randint(0,9,size=(2,2)).astype(np.int))
workspace.FeedBlob("Y", np.random.randint(0,9,size=(2,2)).astype(np.int))

# define a network which adds the two blobs together and
# stores the result as Sum
net = core.Net('net')
sum_stuff = net.Add(["X", "Y"], "Sum")

# run the network
workspace.CreateNet(net)
workspace.RunNet(net.Proto().name)

# get the values from the workspace
X = workspace.FetchBlob("X")
Y = workspace.FetchBlob("Y")
Sum = workspace.FetchBlob("Sum")

# print the result to check if correct
print("First matrix:\n{0}".format(X))
print("Second matrix:\n{0}".format(Y))
print("Sum of the two matrices:\n{0}".format(Sum))
```